# Sort Array with Text and Numbers Numerical

Tags: php, sorting

I tried several sort functions and searched a long time in the internet. But there wasn't any answer.

I have an Array in PHP which looks like this:

```
$array = array('Real life (100%)', 'Computer Games (19%)', 'Sport in Freetime (34%)');
```

Now I want to sort this array by the numbers. Like:

```
array(
        
  [1] => 'Real life (100%)'
  [2] => 'Sport in Freetime (34%)'
  [3] => 'Computer Games (19%)'

)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Would be easier if you created a nested array with the percentages in their own element separate from the text, and just formatted it with the two elements combined for display purposes.... so how are you creating this array?

Comment: @MarkBaker Okay. So do you mean an 2D Array? The code is a bit more complicated, so its too hard to explain how i creating this array: `array_push($topWrongQuestionsEnd, $allSavedQuestions[$i]->question_de . ' [' . round($number) . '%]');`

Comment: `array_push($topWrongQuestionsEnd, [$allSavedQuestions[$i]->question_de, round($number)]);` an then you can sort via `usort($topWrongQuestionsEnd, function($a, $b) { return $a[1] <=> $b[1]});` (using the PHP 7 spaceship operator)

Comment: Or make it an associative array so that it's more easily readable: `array_push($topWrongQuestionsEnd, ['topic' => $allSavedQuestions[$i]->question_de, 'percentage' => round($number)]);` and usort for PHP  version <7 `usort($topWrongQuestionsEnd, function($a, $b) { return $a[percentage] - $b['percentage']});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using `usort` and [***filter_var***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) functions:

```
$arr = ['Real life (100%)', 'Computer Games (19%)', 'Sport in Freetime (34%)'];
usort($arr, function($a,$b){
    return filter_var($b, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) - filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
});

print_r($arr);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Real life (100%)
    [1] => Sport in Freetime (34%)
    [2] => Computer Games (19%)
)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. But i forgot, that i have a text like: 'I am(100% working) have a additional job (65%)'.
How can i only sort by the last number? I tried with a `preg_match` but it doesnt work.

Comment: @david-schor, welcome. The initial input was an array. Your new condition has text as input, that's another case for another solution

Comment: Roman, I think you misunderstand the question extension.  @david-schor I think this is what you are asking for: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/20b099ac3d583a32835dbe02df7b292674c58abf

Comment: @mickmackusa, the title is clear **Sort Array with Text and Numbers Numerical** , that's what my solution does

Comment: ...no, I mean the OP's extension: This is a new element for the sample array: `I am(100% working) have a additional job (65%)`  It has two `(\d+%)`s in the string, he wants to compare the last number when two numbers exist in one string.  He is not changing the input data structure from array to string, he is adding a new element to the sample array.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you very much, that you saw my extension and gave me the right solution!

Comment: @david-schor It is just a misunderstanding about your question extension.  Roman is a very solid coder/poster, and he answered your question as it was originally posted.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes i see! Without him there wouldnt be a solution!

Comment: @mickmackusa, thank you. I just always tend to act pragmatically. And if the situation implies extended input, I think, it was worth to update the question with extended sample